# Fetch API signal abort php sleep

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api, abort

I use the fetch API to insert forms into PHP. It's working fine.
However when I click on the modal close button the request is not terminated.

I'm getting a error in console; DOMException: The operation was aborted.
I know that abort is working.

When I close the modal whitin a few seconds and want to open a new modal it waits until the sleep time is over from the previous one and then starts the new sleep.

Has this someting to do with sleep or with PHP? browser vs server?
Or if I remove sleep will it abort the insert or does php just keep going in the background?

JS

```
function modal() { 
  let formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('id', '1');
  formdata.append('name', 'test');

  let controller = new AbortController();
  let signal = controller.signal;

  
    
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.modal-close'), function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function() {

      controller.abort();
      console.log('post aborted');
      modal_hide();
    });
  });

 fetch('post.php', { method: 'POST', body: formdata,  signal: signal })
   .then(function(response) {
     return response.json();
   })
   .then(function(data) {
     console.log(data.message);
     modal_open();
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.warn('error.', error);
  });
 }
}
```

PHP

```
sleep(10);
$link = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;
$link = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

Comment: Fairly sure this is a server-side thing. The browser will abort the `fetch`, but if the PHP processing has already started, that doesn't mean the PHP stops running. I don't do PHP, but [a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+detect+aborted+request) turned up [`connection_aborted`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) which might be relevant (or not :-) ).

Comment: You don't need to use `[].forEach.call()`. The `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll()` has a `forEach()` method.

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but your code is falling prey to a footgun in the `fetch` API. It only rejects its promise on *network* error, not HTTP error. So if there's an HTTP error (like a 404 or 500), it fulfills its promise (but usually with an HTML or plain text response depending on your server, not JSON -- and in any case, not hte JSON you're expecting). You have to check for that explicitly. I've written it up [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: You shouldn't have that loop that adds the click listeners inside the `modal()` function. Every time you open the modal it will add another listener to the close button.

Comment: There is much more code behind it. This is a example